# How to measure size of response data in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to measure size of response data of multiple http samplers in JMeter. I need to find the overall size of all the responses not for individual responses. I am trying to fetch it through a Beanshell code but it displays the size of the last sample executed:-

```
import java.util.io.*;
import java.lang.io.*;
int totalsize;
test = prev.getResponseDataAsString().length();
log.info("size is = "+test);
totalsize = totalsize + test;
log.info("totalsize is = "+totalsize);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSR223 code with `props` and set JMeter property totalsize with 0 at start

```
 props.put("totalsize", Integer.parseInt(prop.get("totalsize")) + test);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am  trying to use the code in a beanshell post processor. However I am  getting following error :- BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of... and BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval.. Please suggest what can be done for this..Code which I used is :- int totalsize = 0; 
test = prev.getResponseDataAsString().length();
props.put("totalsize", Integer.parseInt(props.get("totalsize")) + test);
log.info("totalsize is = "+totalsize);

Answer (score 0):

Following solution also worked for me on a beanshell post processor:-

```
import java.util.io.*;
import java.lang.io.*;
test = prev.getResponseDataAsString().length();
log.info("size is = "+test);
text = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getName();
log.info("Sampler name is " +text);
if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("Test Sampler")){
props.put("totalsize",Integer.parseInt("0"));
}else{
props.put("totalsize", (props.get("totalsize")!=null?props.get("totalsize"):0) + test);
}
log.info("totalsize is = "+props.get("totalsize"));
```

"test" captures the size of each of the sample requests and keeps adding it to the "totalsize". At the end of the execution I am initializing totalsize back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

it's more appropriate to use `prev.getBytesAsLong()` to get each sampler response size. Take a look at [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getBytesAsLong--)

To have combined size of multiple responses you could try grouping needed requests in transaction via [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller).

[image: grouping of Samplers via Transaction Controller]